# Posting form on website with <noscript>

Tags: android, web

So I am developing an Android application which aims to log into a website and scrape data from the returned page. However, I fail to log into the website using methods such as Jsoup or Apache HttpClient as these methods trigger the  response on the page prompting me to have JavaScript enabled in order to access the page. HtmlUnit would be a good workaround however its large number of JAR's disables me from using this on an Android application.

What should I do to work around/through this  problem?

This is the website I am trying to log into: 
https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/Logon.aspx

Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code for jSoup

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/Logon.aspx")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Username", "myusername")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Password","mypassword")
                .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$LogonButton","Sign in").post();
        System.out.println(doc.text());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And for HtmlUnit

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException{
      final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
      webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://grades.bsd405.org/Pinnacle/Gradebook/InternetViewer/GradeSummary.aspx");

        final HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);

        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$LogonButton");
        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Username");
        final HtmlPasswordInput passField = form.getInputByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Password");

        textField.setValueAttribute("myusername");
        passField.setValueAttribute("mypassword");

        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        displayGrades(page2);

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
}

private static void displayGrades(HtmlPage page) {
    System.out.println(page.asXml());

    HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getHtmlElementById("Content");
    final HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) div.getByXPath("//table[@class='reportTable']").get(0);
    try{
        System.out.println(table.asText());
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show show the code you tried to login with both methods.

Comment: As I have previously stated, HtmlUnit is not a possible option as it can't be ported into a mobile app due to its immense number of JAR files.